# React Native Error on websocket reconnect event

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io

I have  an application on React Native and my websocket doesn't works correctly. The connect event works fine but where it disconnect, dont  reconnect.

When the internet crashes, I have to restart the application for the websocket to work again.

"socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"

```
socket.on('connect_error', (payload) => {
           console.log(`connect_error: ${payload}`)
           console.log(payload)
       });
```

On connect error, I have this payload

```
Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.onError (transport.js:67)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (websocket.js:157)
    at WebSocket.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at WebSocket.js:285
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
    at e (RNDebuggerWorker.js:1)
```

Edit: On device works fine, this error is only simulator

Comment: Did you find any solution to the issue Junior?